# I want to get the first and last date from column DATETIME grouped by columns BANKCASENUMBER and BALANCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to get the first and last date of DATETIME based on the columns BANKCASENUMBER and BALANCE in SQL.

[image]

My code so far is:

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_FILTER_FOR_QUERY_FOR_S AS 
       SELECT t1.ACCOUNTID, 
          t1.BALANCE, 
          t1.DATETIME, 
          t2.TYPE, 
          t2.BANKCASENUMBER
      FROM WORK.FILTER_FOR_QUERY_FOR_SORTSORTED t1
           INNER JOIN TALLY.ACCOUNTDETAILS t2 ON (t1.ACCOUNTID = t2.ACCOUNTS1);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use MAX() and MIN(), do a GROUP BY.

Comment: tag your RDBMS(like sql-server, oracle, postgre)

Comment: Do you want to extract the date value from your datetime value? Or would the min and max datetime value work for you?

Comment: *"Use MAX() and MIN(), do a GROUP BY."* otherwise see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as giving us only a query is not enough infromation to understand your problem and or which results your are after

Comment: I want to extract the date value if that is possible

Comment: *"I want to extract the date value if that is possible"* i assume you mean if you have DATETIME `2019-06-26 00:00:00` you want to have the DATE part `2019-06-26` ? if so the only valid method in ANSI/ISO SQL where the SQL tag is about on stackoverflow is  `EXTRACT(DATE FROM '2019-06-26 00:00:00')` which might not be supported by your database vendor product.

Comment: Use the DATEPART() function to get a date value (number of days) from a datetime value (number of seconds).. Remember to attach an appropriate format so that values display to humans like dates instead of raw numbers.

Comment: @Voodoo The question was already tagged as being SAS code.

Comment: Are ACCOUNTID and TYPE part of the grouping keys?  Or do you want those variable summarized in some way?  Or do you want all of the detail rows kept with the calculated min/max dates attached to all of the observations that contributed to their calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to group the columns according to your needs in `SQL-Server` and use [Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which you do not want to be in Grouping criteria

```
  SELECT 
      t1.ACCOUNTID, 
      SUM(t1.BALANCE), 
      MIN(t1.DATETIME) AS FirstDate, 
      MAX(t1.DATETIME) AS LastDate,
      t2.TYPE, 
      t2.BANKCASENUMBER
  FROM WORK.FILTER_FOR_QUERY_FOR_SORTSORTED t1
       INNER JOIN TALLY.ACCOUNTDETAILS t2 ON (t1.ACCOUNTID = t2.ACCOUNTS1);

  GROUP BY t1.ACCOUNTID, t2.TYPE, t2.BANKCASENUMBER
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland I mean to say that `columns` which he did not want to be grouping criteria like `balance`. I did not mean filtering the records. And also I have corrected my answer

Comment: fair enough then i misinterpret your answer and what you meant to say..